# Corda Performance to call a Flow several times

Tags: corda

We built our application based on cordapp-template-kotlin, and used the **client** folder infrastructure to provide rest services to a consumer who is a web application.

The services receive a list of data that serve as parameters to the flows. And we call the streams chained to each iteration in the data list. For example, the web provides a list of names, and with that list, we create accounts on corda.
We want to improve the performance of our scenario as a whole. And one of the aspects that I thought could improve, would be to parallelize the flow calls. But when I paralleled the creation of accounts, for example, I did not have any performance gain. I would like to know why.

Creating accounts one by one in a linear way had the same performance of doing the creation in a parallel way. Is this the expected behavior or is there a problem in my development?

Comment: Are you on Corda Community/ Enterprise?

Comment: Hi Ashutosh, we use Corda Enterprise with Postgres database. But in fact I did this validation of parallelism on my machine, without enterprise.
In addition I validated the parallelism in a flow test class using Corda's MockNetwork.
Do you think that this change paralleling flow calls will be more efficient with enterprise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corda Opensource doesn't have a multi-threaded flow state machine. Hence you won't be able to benefit from parallel flow execution on Corda Opensource.

A better approach for this with Corda Opensource would perhaps be batching of accounts with a single transaction on flow, rather than creating the accounts with multiple flow invocation.

With Corda Enterprise, however, you could benefit with multi-threaded flow state machine. But I would still recommend exploring the batching approach and find an optimal solution with maximum efficiency.

Comment: Good to know.
Is this an interesting approach for all flows? That's because several of my REST services receive a list of data, not only to create accounts.
And what is the best approach? Create multiple states in a single transaction or send each transaction individually just by grouping it into a single flow call?
And when creating accounts for example, we use the "accountService.createAccount", if I send a list of names to the flow and make the calls linearly to accountService, would there already be a performance gain?